# How to easily convert xml to a different format using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Currently trying to teach myself basic XSLT in a practical environment - wondering what the easiest way to transform this:

```
<fig id="vid1" position="float" fig-type="video">
<label>Video 1</label>
<caption><p>Test video 1</p></caption>
<media xlink:href="test1.mp4" id="test1" mime-subtype="mp4" content-type="play-in-place"/>
</fig>
```

Into this format, along with adding boilerplate text (external-host-filename, Video player) that should be output with every transformation.

```
<media id="vid1" xlink:href="test1.mp4" xlink:role="external-host-filename" content-type="play-in-place">
<object-id pub-id-type="media-player-id">Video Player</object-id>
<object-id pub-id-type="other" content-type="media-stream-id">test 1</object-id>
<label>Video 1</label>
<caption><p>Test video 1</p></caption>
</media>
```

Any input would be great, thanks!

Comment: and what's the problem? are there multiple `fig` nodes on that xml?

Comment: in most cases there will be one, maybe two nodes in the xml. I think the bit I'm struggling with is changing the identifier of the attributes, rather than just the element.

Comment: It's best in such situations to show us your best attempt, and then we can tell you what's missing. No one wants to write a custom tutorial just for you, or to write all the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with your source XML.
As you wrote, that there can by **multiple** `fig` nodes, they must be embedded
in some **single** root element, I called it `root`.

Another requirement is that each used namespace must be somewhere declared,
e.g. in the root element.

So the source XML, including for simplicity a single (your) `fig` element
can be like below:

```
<root xmlns:xlink="urn:xlink">
  <fig id="vid1" position="float" fig-type="video">
    <label>Video 1</label>
    <caption><p>Test video 1</p></caption>
    <media xlink:href="test1.mp4" id="test1" mime-subtype="mp4" content-type="play-in-place"/>
  </fig>
</root>
```

And now move on to the XSLT script.

First of all, you have to repeat in the opening `stylesheet` tag
each namespace used, e.g.: `xmlns:xlink="urn:xlink"`.

To define your boilerplate texts you can use `xsl:param` elements,
defining their names and values, e.g.:

```
<xsl:param name="role" select="'external-host-filename'"/>
<xsl:param name="Object1" select="'Video Player'"/>
```

Then you should write a template matching `fig`, generating a `media` element
with proper attributes and content. E.g. to create `id` attribute you can write:

```
<xsl:attribute name="id" select="@id"/>
```

Sometimes an attribute can be copied from the source, e.g.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="media/@content-type"/>
```

And now a piece of invention: As your output is to contain **two** `object-id`
elements, let's write a single template to generate it with necessary
formal parameters:

```
<xsl:template name="object">
  <xsl:param name="pub-type"/>
  <xsl:param name="content-type" required="no"/>
  <xsl:param name="content"/>
  <object-id>
    <xsl:attribute name="pub-id-type" select="$pub-type"/>
    <xsl:if test="$content-type != ''">
      <xsl:attribute name="content-type" select="$content-type"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$content"/>
  </object-id>
</xsl:template>
```

and call it twice, with proper actual parameters (see below).

The last part of this template is to copy two source elements to
the output, using `copy-of`.
To make the script shorter, I wrote it in a single `copy-of` statement.

And don't forget about the *identity template*.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xlink="urn:xlink">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:param name="role" select="'external-host-filename'"/>
  <xsl:param name="Object1" select="'Video Player'"/>

  <xsl:template match="fig">
    <media>
      <xsl:attribute name="id" select="@id"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href" select="media/@xlink:href"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="xlink:role" select="$role"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="media/@content-type"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="object">
        <xsl:with-param name="pub-type" select="'media-player-id'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="content" select="$Object1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="object">
        <xsl:with-param name="pub-type" select="'other'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="content-type" select="'media-stream-id'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="content" select="'test 1'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:copy-of select="label, caption"/>
    </media>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="object">
    <xsl:param name="pub-type"/>
    <xsl:param name="content-type" required="no"/>
    <xsl:param name="content"/>
    <object-id>
      <xsl:attribute name="pub-id-type" select="$pub-type"/>
      <xsl:if test="$content-type != ''">
        <xsl:attribute name="content-type" select="$content-type"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="$content"/>
    </object-id>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/nb9MWtn

Comment: This is very, very helpful and has really given me an insight into a) what I was doing wrong and b) how to fix it. Much appreciated!